# set edittext text in fragment to a variable value from other fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a `fragment1` that has a variable `x` and a second fragment that has an `Edit Text`,

```
 //this code in fragment 1 onCreateView
 double x = 1.111111

 //txt1 is in fragment2
 EditText txtx =(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
```

When I do the following the app crashes:

```
 txtx.setText(x);
```

Comment: Can you place the stack trace ? Moreover when the view is in second fragment you can't call it from first fragment. I believe it is a null pointer exception. If that is the case, let me know when will the second fragment be loaded and any such details so that i can help you.

Comment: the two fragments is in a tabbed activity

Comment: use fragment activity communication design pattern.

Comment: then you have to set the value in the parent activity and read it from there and set it to the second fragment. If it is a resource not found exception please let me know.

Comment: Grammar, language, capitalization, code layout